# How do I unit test private functions from a separate project in VB .NET?

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, nunit, private, friend

As I develop code, I often want to unit test some of the building blocks of a class even if they are normally private. If my unit tests are inside the project, I can use "Friend" to accomplish this and still keep the functions private for normal use. But I would rather move my NUnit tests into their own separate project(s). How do I achieve the effect I'm looking for?

Answer (score 12):

You can't (easily) test *private* methods from a different project, but it's quite common to test *internal* methods (`Friend` in VB) from a test project using [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx). This makes `Friend` members accessible to another assembly.

Apparently this was new in VB 9 although it was available in C# 2... not quite sure why, but [this blog post from Bart de Smet](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2007/09/01/visual-basic-9-0-feature-focus-friend-assemblies.aspx) gives a quick example.

Note that if your production assembly is signed, your test assembly will need to be signed too, and you'll have to specify the public key in the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` arguments. See [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1123831/22656) for more details.

Comment: As to why it was new in VB9, it was a cost / benefit trade off.  VB has a very different way of resolving names than C# and InternalsVisibleTo very much complicates name lookup.  It was too costly for VB8 and hence fell to VB9.  We are actually making further changes around name resolution to (cont)

Comment: (cont) account for this in VB10.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that information on signing in the context of using `InternalsVisibleto` can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123683/how-to-declare-a-friend-assembly (also answered by Jon!).

Answer (score 3):

You can use Reflection to invoke the private methods.  There are plenty of samples out there to do this.

Comment: And this is the one that helped me the most: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/testnonpublicmembers.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From a quick google search: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/testnonpublicmembers.aspx

The basics: (this is pasted from the code project site linked above)

```
        public static object RunStaticMethod(System.Type t, string strMethod,
  object []  objParams) 
    {
        BindingFlags eFlags = 
         BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | 
         BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        return RunMethod(t, strMethod, 
         null, aobjParams, eFlags);
    } //end of method

    public static object RunInstanceMethod(System.Type t, string strMethod, 
     object objInstance, object [] aobjParams) 
    {
        BindingFlags eFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | 
         BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        return RunMethod(t, strMethod, 
         objInstance, aobjParams, eFlags);
    } //end of method

    private static object RunMethod(System.Type t, string 
     strMethod, object objInstance, object [] aobjParams, BindingFlags eFlags) 
    {
        MethodInfo m;
        try 
        {
            m = t.GetMethod(strMethod, eFlags);
            if (m == null)
            {
                 throw new ArgumentException("There is no method '" + 
                  strMethod + "' for type '" + t.ToString() + "'.");
            }

            object objRet = m.Invoke(objInstance, aobjParams);
            return objRet;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    } //end of method
```