# How to declare a friend assembly?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, assembly-signing

I have 2 projects in my solution:

1. Assembly (Basic Library)
2. Test Assembly (NUnit)

I had declared the test assembly as friends assembly in first project:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo ("Company.Product.Tests")]
```

Everything was working fine till I realised that I have forgot to setup the solution to sign my assemblies. So created a snk file and setup the visual studio project to sign the first assembly (Basic Library). Now when I compile the first project, I get following error:

> Friend assembly reference
>   'Company.Product.Tests' is invalid.
>   Strong-name signed assemblies must
>   specify a public key in their
>   InternalsVisibleTo declarations.

I tried to extract the public key from my snk file using sn utility but it generates a wired binary file which I am unsure how to use. How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 212, accepted):

You need to sign *both* assemblies, because effectively both assemblies reference each other.

You have to put the public key in the InternalsVisibleTo attribute. For example, in Protocol Buffers I use:

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("Google.ProtocolBuffers.Test,PublicKey="+
"00240000048000009400000006020000002400005253413100040000010001008179f2dd31a648"+
"2a2359dbe33e53701167a888e7c369a9ae3210b64f93861d8a7d286447e58bc167e3d99483beda"+
"72f738140072bb69990bc4f98a21365de2c105e848974a3d210e938b0a56103c0662901efd6b78"+
"0ee6dbe977923d46a8fda18fb25c65dd73b149a5cd9f3100668b56649932dadd8cf5be52eb1dce"+
"ad5cedbf")]
```

The public key is retrieved by running

```
sn -Tp path\to\test\assembly.dll
```

Alternatively, get it from the .snk file:

```
sn -p MyStrongnameKey.snk public.pk
sn -tp public.pk
```

Comment: Don't multiple assemblies signed with the same key end up with the same public key? Would this provide an "end-run" around the problem, perhaps?

Comment: @Bevan: Yes, quite possibly. Just compiling a dummy file with the key is probably a faster way to go - will edit.

Comment: If both assemblies are being signed with different keys, I assume I need to specify public key of friend assembly (inside InternalsVisibleTo attribute). Is that right?

Comment: And it is damn irritating to see the MSDN documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) mention ridiculously short public key which almost look like public key **token** to me.

Comment: Hemant: I think at one stage the docs actually claimed it *did* need to be the token. Doh.

Comment: You can extract the public key directly from a .snk file: 
 
sn -k MyStrongnameKey.snk // 

sn -p MyStrongnameKey.snk public.pk  //

sn -tp public.pk //

Comment: @Tim: Thanks, I seem to remember this being corrected in another answer, but not this one. Will edit now.

Comment: Guys.. is there any explanation as to why we need to add the publickey. Why signing the referenced project with same .snk file not enough?

Comment: @Nisarg: The original assembly is trying to express the idea of trusting a different assembly. As an attacker, I shouldn't be able to swap out *your* signed friend assembly for *my* assembly, even if I've managed to sign my assembly with my key.

Comment: How does one know the name of the assembly?

Comment: @ColonelPanic: Um, you're trying to give access to a particular assembly. You should know the name already.

Comment: I was using the 'assembly title' specified in `AssemblyInfo.cs`. Since then deduced the right name to use is the 'assembly name' from the project's Properties/Application dialog (which differs again from project's name in Visual Studio's solution explorer).

Comment: To quickly get Public Key for an assembly you can refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539398.ASPX

Comment: As helpful as these answers and comments have been, I needed some experimentation to realize that the public key is the one from the assembly containing the tests, NOT the assembly that contains the 'InternalsInvisibleTo' declaration.

Comment: @Andreas: Well it goes along with the assembly you're naming - you're specifying the strong name of the assembly to trust, within the assembly that's doing the trusting.

Comment: You put the PK from Google.ProtocolBuffers.Test or ProtoBuf in assembly:InternalsVisibleTo?

Comment: @Ricardo: From the *target*, so in this case `Google.ProtocolBuffers.Test`. You're saying "I want you to trust this assembly".

Comment: the problem with i have is : i can get public key from snk file and can put it into assemblyinfo as `assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("TestServerApi,PublicKey=" + ...`, but right after i compile the project, this publicKey= is gone. i also added same key to csproj itemsgroup: `<ItemGroup><InternalsVisibleTo Include="TestServerApi"  PublicKey="... " />...`, it does not change anything - after build public key is gone from assembly

Comment: @SashaBond: I don't know what you mean by "is gone" - are you modifying a *generated* AssemblyInfo.cs by any chance? If so, don't do that - just add a separate one. I don't quite know what's going on in your situation (and I've never used an MSBuild property for this) but I *do* trust signed assemblies all the time...

Answer (score -3):

You can directrly get publicKey from assembly which you interest,
without magic with sn.exe

```
<!-- language: c# -->
var assemblyName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName();
Console.WriteLine("{0}, PublicKey={1}",
    assemblyName.Name,
string.Join("", assemblyName.GetPublicKey().Select(m => string.Format("{0:x2}", m))));
```

Comment: This is not an answer to _this_ question. It should be a comment on [the answer it is addressing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1123831/1350209)

Answer (score -7):

I think you need to put in the strong name, which would be something like "Company.Product.Tests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17135d9fcba0119f". I assume Company.Product.Tests is your assembly name and 17135d9fcba0119f is the public key.

Another way to resolve this problem would be not to use separate assemblies. I usually put the source code and the testing code in the same assembly. I don't know if you have any special concern that you must separate them.

Comment: I dont think we need to specify the version number and culture (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx). I havent really tried putting the test code in the assembly itself. Will try and see how it works (+1 for the tip).

Comment: For InternalsVisibleTo, PublicKeToken is not enough. You need the entire public key :-(