# Accessing a method defined as `internal` by a FriendAssembly

Tags: c#, assemblies, internal

I have a method declared with `internal static` in one of my classes and i would like to expose this method to another class in a particular assembly can anybody help me with this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your AssemblyInfo.cs file in the assembly that contains your internal method, use the following line:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("OtherAssemblyName")]
```

If you receive the following error...

> Friend assembly reference 'OtherAssemblyName' is invalid. Strong-name signed assemblies must specify a public key in their InternalsVisibleTo declarations.

Then see the modification here: [How to declare a friend assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123683/how-to-declare-a-friend-assembly)

This, however, will give your other assembly visibility into all of your internals in your original assembly.  You can't just expose one internal to a friend assembly.

Answer (score 0):

C# doesn't have *friend* types, it only has *friend* assemblies.
This means that you can't make a specific internal type visible to a specific type in another assembly.

All you can do is to make *all* internal types - *and* internal class members of - visible to *all* classes of another assembly via the [`InternalsVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute.

Comment: The downvoter is encouraged to explain the downvote so I can fix the answer.