# Akka.dll Strong-name signed assemblies must specify a public key in their InternalsVisibleTo declarations.after manually signing the AKKA.DLL

Tags: akka

Getting the error
Akka.dll Strong-name signed assemblies must specify a public key in their InternalsVisibleTo declarations.after manually signing the AKKA.DLL from a command Line

I have signed AKKA.DLL manually from a command Line using the following commands

```
ildasm /all /out="C:\temp\AKKA.il" " E:\Emporos\Projects\MSPOS\Main-branch-SS-Beta\packages\Akka.1.0.6\lib\net45\Akka.dll”
ilasm /dll /key=" E:\Certificate\Ours.snk" "C:\temp\AKKA.il"
```

But now when I use AKKA I get the following error:

```
Akka.dll Strong-name signed assemblies must specify a public key in their InternalsVisibleTo declarations.
```

after manually signing the AKKA.DLL from a command Line.

Any Ideas on how to work around this? I need the DLL signed.

Comment: PLease, format your post. Use `edit` word under your post. We use `{}` button and backticks ```` for code highlighting, set spaces between words. Messy question usually would not recieve clear answers.

Comment: There is no code here. These are command line commands

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1123831) helped guide me to a solution.

Ultimately, I downloaded the [Akka.net source code](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net), added my snk to the Akka project, then added the assembly name of the project consuming the Akka.net dll along with the public key to the AssemblyInfo.cs file in the Akka.net project like below.

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyCompany.Integrations.Crm.Services,PublicKey=" +
"00240000048000009400000006020000002400005253413100040000010001003be31b5689fa8f" + 
"1de77977ce8a45369da533967baf4074228362e63f04dc116cf3713abcf2ed84c77c7dd107c7aa" + 
"e15b9688e53faa71af6b6bf5d767ac6e030edd4dcccca45693bc4c17c969fdb5c282bd1f594b81" + 
"f9c46c1ca81cf119fd73bcf83a875515e1f18695bbdf90bc05ece7b28567f613ea9db23b96fe22" + 
"2ad90b95")]
```

Then compile the Akka.net project and reference that dll in the MyCompany.Integrations.Crm.Services project.